# Webpage MetroUI CSS span two rows on a column

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, layout, metro-ui-css

I am trying to make a grid where it is 3 columns in a windows metro tile format using [MetroUI](http://metroui.org.ua/). The first column has two wide tiles stacked vertically. The second column is a large tile carousel. Then the third column is again two wide tiles stacked vertically. This code does look good but on resizing the browser size it overlaps the tiles and the carousel. What is the correct way of laying this out? Also tried with Bootstrap grid but then get wide margins.

```
<div class="container main-tiles-2">
<div class="tile-area no-padding">
    <div class="tile-container bg-color-tile-light-pantone" style="width: 100%">
        <div class="flex-grid">
            <div class="row cells3 cell-auto-size">
                <div class="tile-container no-padding" style="width: 28%">
                    <div class="tile-wide bg-darkBlue fg-white" data-role="tile">
                        <div class="tile-content iconic">
                            <span class="icon mif-calendar"></span>
                            <span class="tile-label">Calendar</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="tile-wide bg-orange fg-white" data-role="tile">
                        <div class="tile-content iconic">
                            <span class="icon mif-users"></span>
                            <span class="tile-label">Room Bookings</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="cell tile-large ol-transparent" data-role="tile">
                    <div class="tile-content">
                        <div class="carousel" data-role="carousel" data-height="100%" data-width="100%"
                             data-controls="false">
                            <div class="slide">
                                <img src="images/main%20image.jpg" data-role="fitImage"
                                     data-format="fill"
                                     alt="Picture of the Day One">
                            </div>
                            <div class="slide">
                                <img src="images/scenery1.jpg" data-role="fitImage" data-format="fill"
                                     alt="Picture of the Day One">
                            </div>
                            <div class="slide">
                                <img src="images/scenery2.jpg" data-role="fitImage" data-format="fill"
                                     alt="Picture of the Day One">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="tile-container no-padding" style="width: 33%">
                    <div class="tile-wide bg-darkTeal fg-white" data-role="tile">
                        <div class="tile-content iconic">
                            <span class="icon mif-list2"></span>
                            <span class="tile-label">News</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="tile-wide bg-cobalt fg-white" data-role="tile">
                        <div class="tile-content iconic">
                            <span class="icon mif-books"></span>
                            <span class="tile-label">Staff Contacts</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Like this it looks just doesnt resize well:

[image: The layout]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The overriding the CSS to change the margins for grids and also filling the width of the tiles to a larger size of the grid space available.The resize works perfectly now.

```
<!-- First row of tiles -->
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-12 my-column">
        <div class="tile-wide bg-darkBlue fg-white" data-role="tile">
            <div class="tile-content iconic">
                <span class="icon mif-calendar"></span>
                <span class="tile-label">Calendar</span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="tile-wide bg-orange fg-white" data-role="tile">
            <div class="tile-content iconic">
                <span class="icon mif-users"></span>
                <span class="tile-label">Room Bookings</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-12 my-column">
        <div class="tile-large ol-transparent" data-role="tile">
            <div class="tile-content">
                <div class="carousel" data-role="carousel" data-height="100%" data-width="100%"
                     data-controls="false">
                    <div class="slide">
                        <img src="images/main%20image.jpg" data-role="fitImage"
                             data-format="fill"
                             alt="Picture of the Day One">
                    </div>
                    <div class="slide">
                        <img src="images/scenery1.jpg" data-role="fitImage" data-format="fill"
                             alt="Picture of the Day One">
                    </div>
                    <div class="slide">
                        <img src="images/scenery2.jpg" data-role="fitImage" data-format="fill"
                             alt="Picture of the Day One">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-12 my-column ">
        <div class="tile-wide bg-darkTeal fg-white" data-role="tile">
            <div class="tile-content iconic">
                <span class="icon mif-list2"></span>
                <span class="tile-label">News</span>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="tile-wide bg-cobalt fg-white" data-role="tile">
            <div class="tile-content iconic">
                <span class="icon mif-books"></span>
                <span class="tile-label">Staff Contacts</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And the CSS

```
.row {
  padding-bottom: 0px;
  padding-top: 0px;
  margin: 0px;

}
.my-column {

  padding-top: 1px;
  padding-bottom: 1px;
  padding-right: 2px;
  padding-left: 1px;
}


/**
Overrides Metro UI Css
*/
.tile-large {
  width: 99%;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue";

}

.tile-wide {
  width:99%;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue";
}

.tile {
  width: 99%;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue";
}
```

Comment: The question is not about bootstrap.